# Jquery clone() is not cloning html element events

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery(3.6.0) `clone()` function to clone the button and its events but it is not cloning its events.

```js
  // Index.js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let x = 1;
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML += 'button Clicked';
            let clonedBtn = $('#btn').clone(true);
            $(clonedBtn).attr('id', 'btn-' + x);
            $('#heading').after(clonedBtn);
            x++;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// Index.html
    <h1 id="heading">heading</h1>
    <button type="button" id="btn">
            click me!
    </button>
```

Any helpful answer will be appreciated.

Comment: But when I add an event listener on `btn` using jquery. it is working fine

Comment: please edit your question and make at least those parts work which should work. You are targeting `id`s  in javascript which do not exist in your HTML. And NO, if those ids don't exist it also will not work with jquery

Comment: `document.getElementById('btn')` , where's btn id ?

Comment: How you can see work no?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini clonedElement has no event listener and on click it's not update heading

Comment: It works fine for me: every time I click a button, it creates a new button after it. What's the problem?

Comment: I also saw later try to press the first button instead of the last.

Answer (score 3):

The *jquery* clone will clone *jquery* events attached directly to that element (ie not event delegation and not vanilla events):

```js
  var x = 1;
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#heading").append("clicked");
    var btn = $("#btn").clone(true);
    btn.attr("id", "btn-" + x++);
    $('#heading').after(btn);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// Index.html
<h1 id="heading">heading</h1>
<button type="button" id="btn">
  click me!
</button>
```

So the simplest solution is to always use jquery events if you want to clone.

Comment: @freedomn-n what do you mean by vanilla events?

Comment: `document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',` is what we call "vanilla javascript" to identify it as being javascript without any plugin/extension/third-party code (without any additional "flavourings") - ie what you get "out of the box".   This is not *jquery*.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't add `addEventListener` after you clone it like:

```js
// Index.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',addButton);
});
let x = 1;
function addButton() {
  document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML += 'button Clicked';
  let clonedBtn = $('#btn').clone(true);
  $(clonedBtn).attr('id', 'btn-' + x);  
  $('#heading').after(clonedBtn);
  document.getElementById('btn-' + x).addEventListener('click',addButton);
  x++;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// Index.html
<h1 id="heading">heading</h1>
<button type="button" id="btn">
            click me!
    </button>
```

Or you can use `data-attribute` like:

```js
// Index.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.dataset.id == 'btn') {
      document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML += 'button Clicked';
      let clonedBtn = $(e.target).clone(true);
      $(clonedBtn).attr('data-id', 'btn');
      $('#heading').after(clonedBtn);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// Index.html
<h1 id="heading">heading</h1>
<button type="button" data-id="btn"> click me! </button>
```

Pure js solution with `cloneNode/setAttribute/parentNode.insertBefore` like:

```js
// Index.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const heading = document.getElementById('heading');
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.dataset.id == 'btn') {
      heading.innerHTML += 'button Clicked';
      let clonedBtn = e.target.cloneNode(true);
      clonedBtn.setAttribute('data-id', 'btn');   
      e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(clonedBtn, e.target.nextSibling);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
// Index.html
<h1 id="heading">heading</h1>
<button type="button" data-id="btn"> click me! </button>
```

Comment: The question is about why the clone event doesn't work, there are plenty of other (easier) solutions/alternatives (such as jquery's event delegation)

Comment: Yes but seems like he need `addEventListener`, Unlike your answer i propose a different solution for continue to use it. And honestly I always prefer to give an alternative answer to jQuery